# How to emit tuples instead of a list of tuples

Tags: scala, scalding

I have a scalding job that looks like this:

import com.twitter.scalding.{Args, Csv, Job, TextLine}

```
class DataJob(args: Args) extends Job(args) {

  val input = args("input")
  val output = Csv(args("output"), separator = ",")

  def parseLine(x: String):Seq[(String, String, String, String)] = {
    List(("a", "b", "c", "d")) //Returns a list, not a tuple
  }

  TextLine(input).mapTo('line -> ('v1, 'v2, 'v3, 'v4)) {
  x:String => {
    parseLine(x) // this code fails with arity error
  }
  }.write(Csv(args("output")))
}
```

When it runs, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Arity of (class com.twitter.scalding.LowPriorityTupleSetters$$anon$2) is 1, which doesn't match: + ('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4')
```

This is because my `parseLine` function returns a list of tuples but the code expects a single tuple to be emitted. How can I get this code to work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I just needed to change:

`TextLine(input).mapTo('line -> ('v1, 'v2, 'v3, 'v4))`

to:

`TextLine(input).flatMap('line -> ('v1, 'v2, 'v3, 'v4))`

Still not exactly clear why, so any responses would be appreciated!

Comment: flatMap , as the name says, flattens its parameter.
So, previously, you have a list of lines (Textline(input)), in input, which procuded a List(List(tuples)). 

With the flattening, you get a List(tuples), which is what you wanted.

Alternatively, you could have changed parseLine to return directly ("a", "b", "c", "d") instead of List(("a", "b", "c", "d")), and it should work too (and is probably marginally more efficient since you avoid some pointers allocations).